# How to retrieve specific keys when grouping on mongo while using $max on a field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can i retrieve keys beyond the grouped ones from mongodb?

Documents example:

```
{code: 'x-1', discount_value: 10, type: 1}
{code: 'x-2', discount_value: 8, type: 1}
{code: 'x-3', discount_value: 5, type: 2}
```

Query:

```
{
    $match: {
        type: 1
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: null
        discount_value: {$max: '$discount_value'}
    }
}
```

This query will retrieve the max value from discount_value (10) key and the key _id but how i can do to retrieve the code and type key as well if i don't have operation to do those keys?

The current result:

```
{_id: null, discount_value: 10}
```

Expected result:

```
{_id: null, discount_value: 10, type: 1, code: 'x-1'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { type: 1 }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      doc: {
        $max: {
          discount_value: "$discount_value",
          type: "$type",
          code: "$code"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I believe it would get `$max` on field `discount_value` and get respective `type` & `code` values from the doc where `discount_value is max`.

In another way, since you're using `$match` as first stage, I believe your data will be less enough to perform `$sort` efficiently :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { type: 1 }
  },
  {
    $sort: { discount_value: -1 } // sort in desc order
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hlmZUG2KdO7)

**Note :**

Test the first query on DB itself rather than in playground. In first query you can use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) as last stage if you wanted to make `doc` field as root of your document.

Comment: I resumed the query o the post, the original query have nested data, do you think that's ok to use sort in this condition?

Comment: @RafaAcioly : What do you mean by nested data ? Isn't that provided sample matches with data in your DB ?

Comment: my current document is something like : `{start_at: ISODate, end_at: ISODate, type: 1, include: {a: 1, b: 2}, exclude: {a: 1: b: 2}}`...

Comment: @RafaAcioly : Sorting on a field of sub-doc is also ok, Did you try the query ?